# Isomorphic algebras determine diffeomorphic manifolds

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, smoothness

It is a kind of folklore but I would like to see the proof of the following fact: given two smooth manifolds $M$ and $N$ if we assume that the algebras $C^{\infty}_0(M)$ and $C^{\infty}_0(N)$ are isomorphic (as algebras) then $M$ and $N$ are diffeomorphic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Theorem 2.8 on p. 30 of *Models for smooth infinitesimal analysis* by Moerdijk and Reyes.  The theorem works with $C^\infty$ rings, which are a bit more general than algebras of functions.  The advantage is that the proof is short.

Comment: I have already accepted your answer, however I realized that there is one subtle thing.
As you mentioned the notion of $C^{\infty}$ ring is more general than just smooth functions
on manifold however the notion of _morphism_ in this category appears to be more restrictive.
So how one can prove that any homomorphism
of algebras is automatically a $C^{\infty}$ morphism (as defined in Moerdijk's book)?

Comment: I don't know a direct proof.   My answer slyly suggested that looking at the algebra of functions on a smooth manifold as an algebra is a bit silly and that $C^\infty$ rings provide a better framework.   But since I cheated, here is an answer to the question you asked:   Theorem 2.3 on p. 34 of  *$C^\infty$-Differentiable Spaces*  by Juan A. Navarro Gonzalez and Juan B. Sancho de Salas (Springer LNM 1824).